# Delete Selected Images (Checkbox/PHP/MySQL)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have images displayed from Database as follows:

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" />
    <a rel="gallery_group" href="images/big/1.jpg" title="Image 1">
        <img src="images/small/1.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="2" />
    <a rel="gallery_group" href="images/big/2.jpg" title="Image 2">
        <img src="images/small/2.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>
```

So as you see each image has its unique ID *(Its all extracted from the Database which has the ID of the images that exist: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc...)*

What i want is that, when someone for example selected Image 1, 2, 4 *(checkbox ID: 1, 2, 4)* and click submit, it will be send to a function that deletes those images from the database.

- How can i check on submit which checkbox have been selected?
- How can i send them to the function that delete them from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the name and value of the checkbox in order to check if it was checked or not. For example, change your html to this:

```
<li>
  <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="delete_images[]" value="2.jpg" />
  <a rel="gallery_group" href="images/big/2.jpg" title="Image 2">
    <img src="images/small/2.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
</li>
```

delete_images[] will be an array of all of the images that you want to delete. It will only contain the values of the checked check-boxes.

In your function, get all of the images like this: `$images = isset($_REQUEST["delete_images"]) ? $_REQUEST["delete_images"] : null;`

Comment: $images is an array? and $_REQUEST will be triggered after i click submit in the form?

Comment: Yes it will be an array of the check-box values that have been checked. Here is a good article on the php variables $_GET, $_POST, and $_REQUEST: http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/get-post-request

Comment: Thanks! Worked great :D